# JwtBearer Auth with Azure key vault

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, asp.net-core-1.0, azure-keyvault

I wanted to use Azure Key Vault to store key which will be used to create signature for JwtTokens generated by my API.

For Jwt token authentication I use Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer and i configured it like that:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = this.tokenAuthKey;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = this.tokenOptions.Audience;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = this.tokenOptions.Issuer;

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateSignature = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0);
            });
```

So, as you see, this configuration requires to provide full key with private part (IssureSigningKey property). It works fine when my key is stored unprotected in xml file, somewhere in file system and I'm just loading it during application startup. However, there is a problem when i try to store my key in Azure Key Vault (AKV). Since AKV only allows to withdraw public part of the key, Im struggling to make it all work together.

I found out that TokenValidationParameters class has delegate property that i can use to provide my own validator method which would use AKV encrypt/decrypt methods to determine if signature is valid.

The problem is I can't determine how to specify my own method that would generate signature part of JWT token, so that configuration of Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer won't need private key.

My question is: is it possible somehow to specify my own method that creates signature for generated JWT token in JwtBearer configuration or during creation of token using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken?

Comment: I know it's an old post, but maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948426/oauth-bearer-token-authentication-is-not-passing-signature-validation